# 'NoneType' is made when I create a list and error in randrange when I haven't used it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nonetype

```
import random
foundwords = []
wordsDict = {}

with open("text", "r") as file:
    contents = file.read().replace('\n',' ')
words = contents.split(' ')

def findwords(word):
    for i in range(len(words) - 1):
        if words[i] == word:
            if not words[i + 1] == '':
                foundwords.append(words[i + 1])
    return foundwords

for word in words:
    wordsDict.setdefault(word, findwords(word))

# for i in range(len(words) - 1):
#     findwords(words[i])
#     wordsDict.setdefault(words[i], foundwords)
#     del foundwords[:]

def nextword(word):
    wordList = wordsDict.get(word.lower())
    new = wordList[random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)]
    return new

def assemble():
    final = [words[random.randint(0, len(words))].capitalize()]
    final.append(nextword(final[-1]))
    print(final)

assemble()
```

I have tried to create a markov-chain project, however, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    assemble()
  File "main.py", line 28, in assemble
    final.append(nextword(final[0]))
  File "main.py", line 23, in nextword
    new = wordList[random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 220, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 198, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
exited with non-zero status
```

And sometimes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    assemble()
  File "main.py", line 28, in assemble
    final.append(nextword(final[0]))
  File "main.py", line 23, in nextword
    new = wordList[random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)]
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I have no idea how to start fixing this problem. I'm only a beginner programmer, so if my code is inefficient or anything, I apologize. Also, I'm not sure if this ok to post as a question, sorry.

Comment: You error is coming from `new = wordList[random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)]` i.e., from `random.randint` which seems to use `randrange` under the covers...

Comment: It looks like `wordList = wordsDict.get(word.lower())` may be returning an empty list. That then causes a negative upper bound on `random.randint`.

Comment: Looks like your wordList is either 0 or 1 lengthed, since randrange is getting (0, 0, 0)

Comment: Any particular reason you're manually generating a random index for your list instead of just using `random.choice`?

Comment: Also, `None` is being created because you use `.get`: `wordList = wordsDict.get(word.lower())` which will return `None` (or whatever default value you give it) if the value is not in the `dict`. Just use normal dict-access instead, so this won't fail silently: `wordList = wordsDict[word]`